# Python sqlalchemy how to deal with null

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I made a flask webframe,and execute sql update on UI.now I meet a question
an data value is json string content is :

```
{"username":"test","measureid":null}
```

When I use python sqlalchemy to update date:

```
sql="update dh_base_measure_get_10 set json="{\"username\":\"test\",\"measureid\":null}"
db.session.execute(sql)
```

but system get an error message:

```
StatementError: A value is required for bind parameter u'null' (original cause: InvalidRequestError: A value is required for bind parameter u'null')
```

it was caused by ["measureid":null] if ["measureid":""] it can be executed successfully,but [null] error.how to deal with the question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's driver is mistaking `:null` as a named bind parameter instead of a value.  Simply add a space after the colon to make it clear that `null` is a value:

```
sql = """update dh_base_measure_get_10
         set json='{"username": "test", "measureid": null}' """
```

Comment: oh that is great.Thaks lot.

Comment: And there still an question .if i add space between : and null ,it could be execute,but content not right for me.as the jsonstr will be an expect value to compare with other response.how could I trim the space after update sql executed??